# Why shouldn't TypeScript widen types following await or yield?

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, generator, type-narrowing

With strictness enabled, we can see that both generators and asynchronous functions will leave narrowed types narrow following an `await`/`yield` statement, resulting in inaccurate typing.

```js
let value: null | string = null;

function* generatorExample() {
  value = null;
  console.log(`before: ${value}`); // type = null, value = null. OK
  yield;
  console.log(`after: ${value}`); // type = null, but value may be a string. INCORRECT
}

async function promiseExample() {
  value = null;
  console.log(`before: ${value}`); // type = null, value = null. OK
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve));
  console.log(`after: ${value}`); // type = null, but value may be a string. INCORRECT
}
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/dev/bug-workbench/?moduleResolution=3&ts=4.9.3&ssl=2&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=1#code/PTAEAEGcBcCcEsDG0Bco4FcCmAoANltKAG4CGe2aAdhnnqAD6gwJUDmoAvKDXQNw4cAMwxVk8APZUAVKDZYqWWKWgTYAUQAepALYAHAgAoAlKADeOUCXLYuPWngFXEUyBIIA6PBLaGABgBGWEJqWGgAJGZkFFgAvn7GfKAg1jF2vHgANOgAnnpY6Q4eoADyANKWoDnwWHgAJk6gLlRunt6+fqRC0EoRUTZxCUkp0bY6pDmgQaCkzHDw7NnQeQXcGcUAkgByAMIlAEr76jsAKjixgqSQOWKgImLQklSgerASOvCQWFq6Blgm5kqo1W9n4lWarSwXh8-iCIVgYVAkWB8USyTAwMKdCWKyxeGK5UqpAA7qR4ERFMTQAAFN4fL6GQwI1rELCmTgAPmYhBO8B0WAkGGgTKwLLZiXBrncUPa-i6PVgfRRQ3RqTGEymBVmLAWbBx+Txm12ByOp3OOCAA)

The type of `value` inside each function is `string | null`, until they explicitly set it to `null`, at which point it is narrowed correctly to `null`. However after a yield or await statement, it may again be a `null` or `string`, so I would expect TypeScript's code flow analysis to widen the type back up. It doesn't, and as a result the type does not correctly describe the actual runtime type.

I was going to submit this as a bug, but I notice that it's been consistently this way on every version I've checked. I wanted to kick the tires here first and ask if there's a good reason why TypeScript *shouldn't* widen variables following await/yield?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is not related specifcally to *generator functions* or `await`. It is rather a design limitation which affects the whole language. Even a simpler example containing only a function will show this issue.

```
let value: null | string = null;

function fn() {
  value = null

  console.log(`before: ${value}`); // type = null, value = null. OK
  [0].forEach(() => value = "abc")
  console.log(`after: ${value}`); // type = null, but value may be a string. INCORRECT
}
```

This issue has been discussed in detail at [#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) which describes the trade-offs the compiler has to make regarding control flow analysis. There is no concept in TypeScript which can detect possible side effects of function calls, or as your question shows, `await` calls or even `yield`.

The TypeScript team has decided to use an *optimistic* approach where any narrowing efforts of control flow analisys continue to persist, even if possible side effects may have invalidated the narrowing. For now, this is the desired behaviour. A *pessimistic* approach may lead to all kinds of annoyances and problems where one would have to repeatedly narrow down the types because any function calls would widen the type back.

Unless there are any **major** changes to the language like `const` parameters or `const` functions where side effects are not allowed or even `volatile` variables which signal to the compiler that the value may change without notice, we will have to live with the possible unsoundness introduced by this optimistic narrowing approach.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer I was hoping for, and appreciate all of it, as well as the link with the extra backstory. I had a feeling there would be one but was looking too specifically for "await" and "yield" semantics.